# Spring and german letters in URL issue

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am facing this issue while trying to redirect a user from a login page (Spring) to a url that contains special german letters (ä, ö, ü, ß). This is likely not limited to them, but these are important at the moment.
The workflow looks like this:

- User goes to a login page with a redirectUrl request param, for example: `http://www.example.com/login.do?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%25C3%25B6l%2F`, where `%25C3%25B6l` translates to `öl`
- After logging in successfully, the user should be redirected to `http://www.example.com/öl/`. However, the actual URL is `http://www.example.com/�l/`, for some strange reason.

Looking at the URL Redirect trace, seems like (Spring?) encodes the `ö` to `%F6` (Unicode?) instead of `%C3%B6` (UTF-8).

The spring container (Tomcat) is all set to have UTF-8 encodings.
I have also tried encoding and decoding the URL to and from `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8`, but without luck.

What I have also tried and seemed to work was to manually convert the special letters to their UTF-8 encoding (e.g. `string.replace("ö", "%C3%B6");"` and pass the url in that form. However, this is ugly and I would prefer not to do that.

Any suggestions on how to properly handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you are in context of a Spring MVC application, redirects can be implemented using `RedirectView` or simply with the prefix `redirect:` as return value of a controller method. Catch it as `RequestParam` during form initialization and keep it in the session as shown in the following example:

*Model:*

```
public class LoginForm implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String redirectUrl;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

*View:*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginForm" acceptCharset="UTF-8" action="login/doLogin">
            <table>
                <tr>
                   <td><form:label path="username">User Name</form:label></td>
                   <td><form:input path="username"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="password">Password</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="password"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Controller:*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login")
@SessionAttributes(LoginController.FORM_NAME)
public class LoginController {

    static final String FORM_NAME = "loginForm";
    private static final String DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "https://google.com";

    @ModelAttribute(FORM_NAME)
    public LoginForm createForm() {
        return new LoginForm();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute(FORM_NAME) LoginForm loginForm, @RequestParam(required = false) String redirectUrl) {
        loginForm.setRedirectUrl(redirectUrl);
        model.addAttribute(FORM_NAME, loginForm);
        return "login/login-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/doLogin")
    public String processFormCredentials(LoginForm loginForm) {
        // input validation omitted ...
        return "redirect:" + (loginForm.getRedirectUrl() != null ? loginForm.getRedirectUrl() : DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL);
    }
}
```

Using this code, the redirect with umlauts works fine on Tomcat - `http://<url>/login?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%25C3%25B6l%2F` redirects on form submission to `http://www.example.com/öl/`.